# EF6 Query ToDictionary with Key as FieldName and Value as Property Value in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

**My DataBase**

```
id UserName       UserLevel       UserEmail
-- -------------- --------------- -----------------
 1 JohnDoe        1               johndoe@acme.com
 2 UserTest       2               linda@acme.com
```

**My Query:**

```
Dim MyQuery = (From U in DB.Users _
               Select U).FirstOrDefault
```

**What I need to accomplish in VB.NET is:**

A Dictionary "KeyValuePair" that output all "Entity Properties Name" and respective value:

```
DBFieldName, Value of Row
------------  ----------------
Username    , johndoe
UserLevel   , 1
UserEmail   , johndoe@acme.com
```

Imagine if you need to generate a text file with this layout (first number is a line number):

```
1: Username, johndoe
2: UserLevel, 1
3: UserEmail, johndoe@acme.com
```

**So far that´s what I have:**

```
Dim MyQuery = (From U in DB.Users _
                   Select U).FirstOrDefault

Dim mydict As EFDictionary = ToEFDictionary(Of Users)(MyQuery)


<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToEFDictionary(Of T)(ByVal Source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As EFDictionary
    Dim EFDictionary As New EFDictionary
    Dim Item As T
    For Each Item In Source
        Dim Properties = Item.GetType().GetProperties
        For Each p In Properties
            Try
                EFDictionary.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(Item)) ' Loading Lazy Table, I need to Qualify these Properties before add, otherwise will load all the lazy tables.
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New Exception("Error loading Lazy Table")
            End Try
        Next
    Next
    Return EFDictionary
End Function


Public Class EFDictionary
    Inherits Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, String))
        MyBase.New(dictionary)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't understand the Dictionary part.

Comment: A Dictionary has a Key and a Value. You have 3 properties, so how does that line up? Tell us what your doing so we can help.

Comment: The pair of Key should be the DB Field Name as a Key and the value should be the DB value of the field.

Comment: Sorry, that does not make sense - could you show the structure of this output? You know the Keys must be unique right?

Comment: Dictionaries only have 1 key, can you see why your words are confusing? Please tell us in detail what your doing and how it to be used. If you have more than 1 record you can't have `CustomerID:1 CustomerName` as the key.

Comment: So you just want to display the data possibly in just a string with some formatting?

Comment: @OneFineDay you don´t really understand what I need to accomplish here don´t you?

Comment: Can you count the number of times I have asked for some details - of course not. What may seem perfectly clear in your mind is just not coming across in your words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited to support Anonymous types, that inherit directly from Object.
In the same way you can use it for every class because it inherits from Object and GetType() is an Object Method.

You can use reflection.

An example:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim cls As TestClass = New TestClass()

        cls.First = "Test"
        cls.Second = 125

        Dim result As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

        result = GetPropertiesNamesAndValues(cls, result)

        Dim product = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", .Price = 1.29}

        result = GetPropertiesNamesAndValues(product, result)

        Dim count As Integer = 1
        For Each r In result
           Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", count, r)
           count += 1
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetPropertiesNamesAndValues(cls As Object, res As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
        Dim props As PropertyInfo() = cls.GetType().GetProperties()

        For Each p As PropertyInfo In props
            res.Add(String.Format("{0} , {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(cls, Nothing).ToString()))
        Next

       Return res
    End Function
End Module
```

where TestClass is made of a pair of properties:

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private _first As String
    Private _second As String

    Public Property First As String
        Get
            Return _first
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _first = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Second As String
        Get
            Return _second
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _second = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: For static classes will work, but for Linq result from a DB query did not.

Comment: That is a great way, but I don't think we are on the right path yet. I wish the OP would tell us why they are doing this and how it is to be used. I think there is a design flaw poss. Maybe Anonymous types would be it.

Comment: @AngeloBestetti: Entity Framework uses POCO's to load data in memory, DB.Users is a class defined somewhere in your solution. If you give us more details we can understand what's going wrong.

Comment: @Rodrigo Taboada, o que eu preciso é quando eu faco uma query em linq gerar o resultado em um dicionario e mas no dicionario eu preciso do nome do campo e o value é o conteudo do campo, assim fico com um dicionario de campo, valor. Depois eu vou usar este dicionario em um template de html para trocar strings tipo "Users.UserName" pelo conteudo que esta no dicionario assim eu monto um html personalizado para ser enviado via email.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop thru this `List(Of String)` for the file. It must be an instance of the class you pass to this function.

```
Public Function GetPropertiesNamesAndValues(Of TClass As Class)(cls As TClass) As List(Of String)
  Dim result As New List(Of String)
  Dim props As PropertyInfo() = cls.GetType().GetProperties()
  For Each p As PropertyInfo In props
    result.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(cls, Nothing)))
  Next
  Return result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim user = (From U In DB.Users Where U.UserLevel = 1).FirstOrDefault
If Not user Is Nothing Then
  Dim userInfo = GetPropertiesNamesAndValues(user)
  'print results
End If
```

Comment: Almost there, see you are hardcoding the name of the field "Username, Userlevel, Useremail" what I need is generate without knowing the fields names, like any query I can translate do a dictionary.

Comment: Then you will need reflection. Did you try *Danilo's* answer - it just needs some modification for your needs.

Comment: You can't combine my answer this Danilo's. Look at it again. I have a Usage part that shows how to call it. You don't need a Dictionary.

Comment: @AngeloBestetti, answer updated so you can pass any class to it.

Comment: Almost there, it worked but I´m using a model with Lazy Loading, when looping thru the elements it tries to "Load" tables related in the model. I´m just trying to figure out how to add to dict just Integers, Strings, decimals etc.